# Verify RSA signature with LockBox

Tags: delphi, lockbox-3, lockbox-2

I would like to verify a digital signature with LockBox3 (or LockBox2 if version 3 isn't suitable for whatever reason).

I have a public key file in PEM form (I can't create new keys with LockBox, because I need to use and existing key pair that is used in other places already):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDEDtIRT57TJAfmub2RsIM32jdo
8ijsds/u1fpY6hwtkC01/LFJkNTXqSwvpaO5tp86o0SlzBHdF0WxPtsKqdc8F7kQ
uHm7hUTLX0zPGRdGCsy9q/PIGlVGAFTBSVXl+grmGGZuS1CHI13L/oulBGENQOxO
8r6D1RyPjt6z0BAndQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I don't know which format to provide to LockBox as a public key. 
I tried converting PEM to XML and used the RSAKeyValue>Modulus part, because it looks close to what is used in the test case, but it didn't work either.
(The public keys here are only an example and have been taken from the converter I've used: https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter)

Unfortunately, whatever I've tried, I didn't manage to use it as the public key in LockBox to verify a signature of a message.

This is what I have so far based on `uLockBox_Signatory_TestCases.pas`:

```
function VerifySignatureLockBox(const AMessage, ASignature: String): Boolean;
const
  //MyPublicKey = 'MIGfMA0GC...';
  MyPublicKey =
    'xA7SEU+e0yQH5rm9kbCDN9o3aPIo7HbP7tX6WOocLZAtNfyxSZDU16ksL6' +
    'WjubafOqNEpcwR3RdFsT7bCqnXPBe5ELh5u4VEy19MzxkXRgrMvavzyBpV' +
    'RgBUwUlV5foK5hhmbktQhyNdy/6LpQRhDUDsTvK+g9Ucj47es9AQJ3U=';
var
  Lib: TCryptographicLibrary;
  Signatory: TSignatory;
  Codec: TCodec;
  MessageStream, SignatureStream: TStringStream;
  KeyStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Lib := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Codec := TCodec.Create(nil);
  Signatory := TSignatory.Create(nil);

  MessageStream := TStringStream.Create(AMessage);
  SignatureStream := TStringStream.Create(ASignature);
  KeyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Base64_to_stream(AnsiBytesOf(MyPublicKey), KeyStream);

    MessageStream.Position := 0;
    SignatureStream.Position := 0;
    KeyStream.Position := 0;

    Codec.CryptoLibrary := Lib;
    Codec.StreamCipherId := RSA_ProgId;
    Codec.ChainModeId:= CBC_ProgId;
    Codec.AsymetricKeySizeInBits := 256;

    Signatory.Codec := Codec;
    Signatory.LoadKeysFromStream(KeyStream, [partPublic]); //<-- ERROR

    Result := Signatory.Verify(MessageStream, SignatureStream) = vPass;
  finally
    Codec.Burn;
    Lib.Free;
    Codec.Free;
    Signatory.Free;

    MessageStream.Free;
    SignatureStream.Free;
    KeyStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This fails at `LoadKeysFromStream()`, more specifically at `StoreStream.ReadBuffer( L, SizeOf( L));` in `uTPLb_RSA_Engine / LoadHugeCardinal_IfNotAlready()` with a `EStreamError` exception.

What am I doing wrong? Could someone please provide a working example?

Comment: Seems identical to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853481/lockbox-3-load-public-key-not-possible-stream-reading-error

Comment: Well, the core issue might be the same, but in a slightly different case. The linked question hasn't found a solution. The linked LockBox forums aren't available anymore. I've tried the "-RSAPublicKey_out" suggestion, but the result is a "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----" which also doesn't work (or I don't know how to use it in this case). Since the other topic is almost 4 years old and LB3 was in development, I was hoping someone could show a working solution for the current version. If it's not compatible by design, I'd also accept a LB2 solution.

Comment: I have no experience with Lockbox 3 but I can tell you that your Key fails with an ASN.1 error when used with code similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431479/jpk-cryptoapi-rsa-256-ecb-pkcs1-one-time-secret-password-encryption-with-publ

Comment: I've made some changes to v3.7, at least the Demo now allows Verifying a sig with a Public RSA Key: https://github.com/fschetterer/tplockbox

Answer (score -1):

Look at this method:

```
LoadKeysFromStream(KeyStream, [partPublic]);
```

The KeyStream must not contain only binary public key.
It tries to load from stream some information about version, header, PartSet and other.

Comment: Hi Алешин Игорь, your post seems not bad. If you wonder why you got downvotes (none by me), I think it is possible that a few users expressed their desire for a more careful language.